# Ignoring redirects when POSTing from Python Requests module?

Tags: python, django, post, request

I use this script to access my Django server and retrieve a CSRF token which then simply attempts to POST data to a view:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7
import sys, time
import requests

username = 'root'
password = 'pass'

fileName, userFolder, uploadFolder = sys.argv

URL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/login/'
client = requests.session()

# Retrieve the CSRF token first
client.get(URL)  # sets cookie
if 'csrftoken' in client.cookies:
    csrftoken = client.cookies['csrftoken']

login_data = dict(username=username, password=password, csrfmiddlewaretoken=csrftoken, next='')
r = client.post(URL, data=login_data, headers=dict(Referer=URL))
```

But in my Django development server's access log I see:

```
[03/Dec/2018 17:44:17] "GET /admin/login/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1637
[03/Dec/2018 17:44:17] "POST /admin/login/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
Not Found: /accounts/profile/
[03/Dec/2018 17:44:17] "GET /accounts/profile/ HTTP/1.1" 404 9904
```

What I don't understand is why I keep getting an additional Get and 404?

Is it possible to configure my Python request to ignore any kind of redirect signal regardless it be for a GET or POST or `session.get()`?

I have tried adding `allow_redirects=False` to `client.get(URL, allow_redirects=False)` but that did not help.

My POSTs are working fine, I'm simply trying to eliminate the additional GET request and it's unnecessary clutter/overhead.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Django redirects to `/accounts/profile/` after a successful login.

To stop requests from following the redirect, you should use `allow_redirects=False` in the `session.post()` call.